# Multivariate stochastic time series forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, stochastic-processes

I have a multivariate time series like this

```
Time      Price      Volume       Buy_Side_Broker_Type   Sell_Side_Broker_Type
09:00:00  4.590       60              HiInfBroker           LInfBroker
09:00:23  4.662       34              MInfBroker            LInfBroker
09:00:45  4.562       41              LInfBroker            HiInfBroker
```

I want to forecast the price using volume and Buy side broker type and sell side broker type as independent variables. How to do it for such stochastic process in R?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest would be an ARIMA model with price as the dependent variable and volume and brokers as exogenous regressors. But stock prices and other financials are notoriously difficult to forecast...

Comment: i think u can use stochvol package with R programm also winbugs is useful